# Loading SVG with Webpack5

Tags: svg, webpack, webpack-5, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to migrate our package from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5 but have issue with svg loading.

Previously, we use HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin and raw-loader in our webpack config.

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inlineSource: '.(js|css)$',
        template: <>,
        filename: <>,
        inject: 'head',
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(),
]
...
module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(svg)$/,
          loader: 'raw-loader',
        },
```

Here is the html file:

```
<button id="button" type="button">
  ${require('../../node_modules/open-iconic<link to svg>').default}
</button>
```

Expected output:

```
<button id="button" type="button">
  <svg ...>
   <path/>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Both of `HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin` and `raw-loader` are deprecated in Webpack 5. For `HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin`, I replaced with `InlineChunkHtmlPlugin` from `react-dev-utils` and for `raw-loader` I tried to follow the [asset module guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) but it did not work (the import statement is not updated).

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inlineSource: '.(js|css)$',
        template: <>,
        filename: <>,
        inject: 'head',
  }),
  new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [new RegExp(`<output name>`)]),,
]
...
module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(svg)$/,
          type: 'asset/source'
        },
```

Does anyone know if I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `asset/source` module type to export the source code of the SVG asset. Previously achievable by using `raw-loader`.
- By default, `html-webpack-plugin` will use [ejs loader](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/main/lib/loader.js) process the html template content. So we can use `require()` to load the SVG files.

Directory structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I 'node_modules|dist'
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── down-arrow-download-svgrepo-com.svg
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js

1 directory, 6 files
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.svg$/, type: 'asset/source' }],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
        }),
    ],
};
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button
            id="button"
            type="button"
        >
            <%= require('./down-arrow-download-svgrepo-com.svg') %>
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

`down-arrow-download-svgrepo-com.svg`:

```
<svg height="800px" width="800px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#47CEAC;" d="M0,256.006C0,397.402,114.606,512.004,255.996,512C397.394,512.004,512,397.402,512,256.006
    C512.009,114.61,397.394,0,255.996,0C114.606,0,0,114.614,0,256.006z"/>
<path style="fill:#36BB9A;" d="M509.685,290.004c-0.137-0.117-198.544-198.699-199.124-199.124
    c-1.274-1.739-3.232-2.942-5.553-2.942h-98.016c-3.867,0-7.002,3.132-7.002,7.002v175.028h-84.014c-2.831,0-5.385,1.702-6.468,4.321
    c-1.084,2.619-0.485,5.627,1.515,7.63c0,0,140.023,140.091,140.025,140.092c0,0,1.493,1.493,1.494,1.494
    c0,0,76.207,76.208,76.209,76.21l1.353,1.353C424.853,472.461,496.35,390.441,509.685,290.004z"/>
<path style="fill:#F4F6F9;" d="M402.491,274.289c-1.084-2.619-3.637-4.321-6.468-4.321h-84.014V94.94
    c0-3.87-3.135-7.002-7.002-7.002h-98.016c-3.867,0-7.002,3.132-7.002,7.002v175.028h-84.014c-2.831,0-5.385,1.702-6.468,4.321
    c-1.084,2.619-0.485,5.627,1.515,7.63l140.022,140.092c1.316,1.313,3.098,2.051,4.954,2.051c1.856,0,3.637-0.738,4.954-2.051
    l140.022-140.092C402.976,279.916,403.574,276.908,402.491,274.289z M256,407.154L132.875,283.97h74.117
    c3.867,0,7.002-3.132,7.002-7.002V101.94h84.014v175.028c0,3.87,3.135,7.002,7.002,7.002h74.117L256,407.154z"/>
</svg>
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset index.html 1.69 KiB [compared for emit]
asset main.js 1.17 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
./src/index.js 1 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 100 ms
```

`dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script></head>
    <body>
        <button
            id="button"
            type="button"
        >
            <svg height="800px" width="800px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#47CEAC;" d="M0,256.006C0,397.402,114.606,512.004,255.996,512C397.394,512.004,512,397.402,512,256.006
    C512.009,114.61,397.394,0,255.996,0C114.606,0,0,114.614,0,256.006z"/>
<path style="fill:#36BB9A;" d="M509.685,290.004c-0.137-0.117-198.544-198.699-199.124-199.124
    c-1.274-1.739-3.232-2.942-5.553-2.942h-98.016c-3.867,0-7.002,3.132-7.002,7.002v175.028h-84.014c-2.831,0-5.385,1.702-6.468,4.321
    c-1.084,2.619-0.485,5.627,1.515,7.63c0,0,140.023,140.091,140.025,140.092c0,0,1.493,1.493,1.494,1.494
    c0,0,76.207,76.208,76.209,76.21l1.353,1.353C424.853,472.461,496.35,390.441,509.685,290.004z"/>
<path style="fill:#F4F6F9;" d="M402.491,274.289c-1.084-2.619-3.637-4.321-6.468-4.321h-84.014V94.94
    c0-3.87-3.135-7.002-7.002-7.002h-98.016c-3.867,0-7.002,3.132-7.002,7.002v175.028h-84.014c-2.831,0-5.385,1.702-6.468,4.321
    c-1.084,2.619-0.485,5.627,1.515,7.63l140.022,140.092c1.316,1.313,3.098,2.051,4.954,2.051c1.856,0,3.637-0.738,4.954-2.051
    l140.022-140.092C402.976,279.916,403.574,276.908,402.491,274.289z M256,407.154L132.875,283.97h74.117
    c3.867,0,7.002-3.132,7.002-7.002V101.94h84.014v175.028c0,3.87,3.135,7.002,7.002,7.002h74.117L256,407.154z"/>
</svg>

        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```